# When sending an email with smtp in python my \t are replaced with a single space.

Tags: python, smtp

I need to be able to have tabs in the email i send so the content can be copy pasted into excel. Code:

```
SUBJECT = subj
TO = [whoto]
FROM = whofrom
BODY = string.join((
    "From: %s" % FROM,
    "To: %s" % ", ".join(TO),
    "Subject: %s" % SUBJECT ,
    "",
    text
    ), "\r\n")

server = smtplib.SMTP(host)
server.login(log,pass)
server.sendmail(FROM, TO, BODY)
server.quit()
```

My text has tabs in it but when the email is sent there are no tabs. How can i get the tabs to remain.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using the mime encoder libraries:

```
from email.MIMEMultipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.MIMEBase import MIMEBase
from email.MIMEText import MIMEText
from email.Utils import COMMASPACE, formatdate
from email import Encoders
import os
import smtplib
import datetime
import logging

class mailer:
    def __init__(self,SERVER="my.mail.server",FROM="email@mydomain.com"):
        self.server = SERVER
        self.send_from = FROM
        self.logger = logging.getLogger('mailer')

    def send_mail(self, send_to, subject, text, files=[]):
        assert type(send_to)==list
        assert type(files)==list
        if self.logger.isEnabledFor(logging.DEBUG):
            self.logger.debug(' '.join(("Sending email to:",' '.join(send_to))))
            self.logger.debug(' '.join(("Subject:",subject)))
            self.logger.debug(' '.join(("Text:",text)))
            self.logger.debug(' '.join(("Files:",' '.join(files))))
        msg = MIMEMultipart()
        msg['From'] = self.send_from
        msg['To'] = COMMASPACE.join(send_to)
        msg['Date'] = formatdate(localtime=True)
        msg['Subject'] = subject
        msg.attach( MIMEText(text) )
        for f in files:
            part = MIMEBase('application', "octet-stream")
            part.set_payload( open(f,"rb").read() )
            Encoders.encode_base64(part)
            part.add_header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename="%s"' % os.path.basename(f))
            msg.attach(part)
        smtp = smtplib.SMTP(self.server)
        mydict = smtp.sendmail(self.send_from, send_to, msg.as_string())
        if self.logger.isEnabledFor(logging.DEBUG):
            self.logger.debug("Email Successfully Sent!")
        smtp.close()
        return mydict
```

Make sure to check the return dictionary, as it will let you know if only some people received the email.

Comment: This is not at all what i asked for. I don't have any problems with sending the email. I just need the tabs to be tabs in the sent email.

Comment: @wDroter If you read the function send_mail, you will note that it uses the mime libs to create the text, instead of creating one big string. This will keep the tabs in your text section, and let you add file attachments if you are so inclined later. The rest of it is just for convenience.

Comment: This also still leaves only spaces and not tabs.

Comment: @wDroter How are you adding the tabs anyway? `\t` in a string?

Comment: @wDroter the line that adds the text to the message is `msg.attach( MIMEText(text) )`. Try adding `print MIMEText(text)` below it, and see if you still have tabs in the output. If you do, then they are being added to your message, and I'd look at the email client you're using for testing. It may be converting tabs to spaces.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to switch your email to be HTML and use tables. In my case Gmail is converting the Email output from tabs to spaces to make it look correct.

To confirm this is your issue. Look at the raw email and try to copy and paste that in.